# How do I add libraries to my git repository but not track them?

Tags: git, repository

I am using the DataTables jquery plugin in a project.  I cloned the project into my libs/ folder and added it to my .gitignore file like this:

jslibs/DataTables/

When I cloned my own repo on another computer I didn't get the DataTables files.   I guess this is because I was ignoring the directory.  I need the files in DataTables for my project but did not want to track them since I had no need to modify them and they are part of their own repoo.

How can I make sure that when I clone my repo I get the DataTables files but still don't track them?

Comment: If you ignore the files, you won't get them when you pull. What's wrong with just tracking them? You don't have to modify them just because they are tracked. Or you can add them as a submodule as well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

In short: `git submodule add https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables.git`